# Is there a way to store comments related to GradeValue for a Numeric GradeObject in Desire2Learn?

Tags: desire2learn

When posting a GradeValue, I'd like to be able to offer explanations for the grade via comments that are stored with the Numeric GradeObject. Is this possible? Can it be done via the Valence Learning Framework APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Valence Learning Framework API does not provide a way to record comments along with assigned grade values.